# What is the meaning of the output of sensor_rate in this code?

Tags: python, image-processing

_, img = cap.read()
zeros_image = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1), np.uint8)

```
img_ycrcb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_ycrcb, (11, 11), 0)

skin_ycrcb_min = np.array((0, 0, 140))
skin_ycrcb_max = np.array((65, 253, 255))
skin_ycrcb_min = np.array((0, 0, 180))
skin_ycrcb_max = np.array((140, 255, 255))
mask = cv2.inRange(blur, skin_ycrcb_min, skin_ycrcb_max)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2:]
valid_cntrs = []
for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    cX = int(x + (w/2))
    cY = int(y + (h/2))

    if (x <= 600) & (y >= 300) & (y <= 455) & (area > 900):
        valid_cntrs.append(cnt)
        cv2.putText(img, str(f'{cX},{cY}'), (cX, cY), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    1, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.rectangle(zeros_image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255),
                      thickness=cv2.FILLED)

mask1 = np.zeros((zeros_image.shape[0], zeros_image.shape[1], 1), np.uint8)
mask_result = cv2.bitwise_or(zeros_image, zeros_image, mask=Sensor1.mask)
white_cell_number = np.sum(mask_result == 255)
sensor_rate = white_cell_number/Sensor1.full_mask_area
```

sensor_rate prints out values between 0.85 to 31 or less than 0.85

Comment: Where you get that code? Do you have any manual or docs? What it is supposed to do?

Comment: @Daweo This a variation of a code found in github

(link: https://github.com/dcrcruz/car-counting-with-python/blob/master/counting_car_1.py)

Its supposed to detect and count moving objects as they pass through a certain line. So everytime an object passes through that line, it counts it and it prints 'result' with those values.

Comment: so you removed the comments from the original code and then ask what the code is doing? how does that make any sense? you also left out other important lines that would tell us what Sensor1 actually is. at least you provided a link to the repositiory...

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original code:

```
    # detect whether there is car via bitwise_and
    mask1=np.zeros((zeros_image.shape[0],zeros_image.shape[1],1),np.uint8)
    mask_result=cv2.bitwise_or(zeros_image,zeros_image,mask=Sensor1.mask)
    white_cell_number=np.sum(mask_result==255)

    # detect to control whether car is passing under the red line sensor
    sensor_rate=white_cell_number/Sensor1.full_mask_area
```

`white_cell_number` is the number of white pixels in `mask_result`.

`sensor_rate` is the ratio of white pixels vs the number of total pixels in `Sensor1.full_mask_area`.

Looking further up int he code:

```
class Sensor:
    def __init__(self,kordinat1,kordinat2,frame_weight,frame_lenght):
        self.kordinat1=kordinat1
        self.kordinat2=kordinat2
        self.frame_weight=frame_weight
        self.frame_lenght =frame_lenght
        self.mask=np.zeros((frame_weight,frame_lenght,1),np.uint8)*abs(self.kordinat2.y-self.kordinat1.y)
        self.full_mask_area=abs(self.kordinat2.x-self.kordinat1.x)
        cv2.rectangle(self.mask,(self.kordinat1.x,self.kordinat1.y),(self.kordinat2.x,self.kordinat2.y),(255),thickness=cv2.FILLED)
        self.stuation=False
        self.car_number_detected=0


video=cv2.VideoCapture("video1.mp4")
ret,frame=video.read()
cropped_image= frame[0:450, 0:450]
fgbg=cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
Sensor1 = Sensor(
    Kordinat(1, cropped_image.shape[1] - 35),
    Kordinat(340, cropped_image.shape[1] - 30),
    cropped_image.shape[0],
    cropped_image.shape[1])
```

`Sensor1.full_mask_area` is a rectangle defined by two points.

So `sensor_rate` is the fill rate of that rectangle.

Comment: Hi @Piglet! Thanks for the feedback. I apologize for leaving out the rest of the code, this is not an original code of mine, I just got left with it and now I'm trying to deconstruct it plus I'm really new to this. May I ask what is fill rate and does it have a unit? I just really need to know why do I need that value because it seems to be the basis of the detection of counting the object.

I created a repository of the whole code here::
https://github.com/dcrcruz/shell-detect/blob/main/shell-detect.py

I really need help thank you so much.

Comment: no, pixel counts don't have a unit and so does their ratio. it is simply number of white pixels divided by number of total pixels.  so a sensor_rate of 1 means all pixels are white, 0.5 -> half the pixels are white. 0 -> all pixels are black.... simple maths.

Comment: the naming of those variables is not very good though. maybe forget about this example. the essence is that they count contour pixels inside a rectangle.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate the help, thank you so much! @Piglet